# Disable Paperclip processing of images when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip

Is there any way to disable paperclip's processing of images when testing with rspec to make them a bit faster / not relying on ImageMagick's method convert?

I'm trying something like

```
allow_any_instance_of(Paperclip::Attachment).to receive(:save){
  FileUtils.cp theFilePathOriginal, '/paperclip/test/processed_filename'
  FileUtils.cp theFilePathSmall, '/paperclip/test/processed_filename_small'
  FileUtils.cp theFilePathThumb, '/paperclip/test/processed_filename_thumb'
}
```

However, I'm having problems getting the `theFilePathOriginal` dynamically (so `theFilePathOriginal` has the file name, `fun.png` for instance, rather than `party.png`). Any ideas?